# Fetch list of entities then set them in many to many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine in the project.

I got a class `Card`

```
class Card implements \JsonSerializable
    {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sign;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $number;

   /**
     * Card constructor.
     *
     * @param $sign
     * @param $number
     */
    public function __construct($sign, $number)
    {
        $this->sign = $sign;
        $this->number = $number;

        $this->id = \sprintf('%s_%s', $sign, $number);
    }
}
```

And a class `CardPicker` that contains `Card`

```
class CardPicker
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Card that could be picked.
     *
     * Many CardPicker have Many Card.
     *
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Card", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @JoinTable(name="available_picker_cards",
     *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="card_picker_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $availableCards;

public function setCards(array $cards): void
    {
        $this->availableCards = new ArrayCollection($cards);
    }
}
```

I have persisted some cards in my database. And I want to init my `CardPicker`. So I write this method:

```
 public function initCardPicker(): CardPicker
    {
        // fetch all wanted cards and put them in CardPicker
        $cards = $this->cardRepository->findAll();

        $cardPicker = new CardPicker();

        $cardPicker->setCards($cards);

        return $this->repository->save($cardPicker);
    }
```

But I got this error message: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: card.id (500 Internal Server`

It seems that when I save the `CardPicker` it tries to `re-persist` my cards which should be unique in my system.

Did I do something wrong with mappings?

EDIT

The repository:

```
/**
 * @method CardPicker|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method CardPicker|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method CardPicker[]    findAll()
 * @method CardPicker[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CardPickerRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CardPicker::class);
    }

    /**
     * Save cardPicker and return it.
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function save(CardPicker $picker): CardPicker
    {
        $this->_em->persist($picker);
        $this->_em->flush();
        $this->_em->clear();

        return $picker;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any special logic in `CardPicker::setCards()`? What does your repository's `save()` method do exactly?

Comment: Can you show the complete entity classes? So faster we can help you in solving the problem.

Comment: Cardpicker and repository added

Comment: @janh CardPicker updated

Comment: @Aleksandr updated

Comment: @GrenierJ Why are you using `entityManager#clear` after `flush`? That will detach the entities from the manager so it no longer knows about them. If you save them again by using `persist`, it will treat them as new entities. IF you need to detach them with `clear` (you probably don't need to), use `merge` to reintroduce them again without treating them as new.

Comment: @janh I used `clear` in another project to avoid error on multiple editing ( entity is not updated without clear) and I forgot to remove it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@grenierj I created classes, and they worked for me.

execute after create entity

```
php bin/console doctrine:migration:diff
php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate
```

config/services.yaml

```
    App\Repository\CardRepository:
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine'

    App\Entity\CardPicker:
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine'
            - 'App\Repository\CardRepository'
```

App/Entity/Card.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CardRepository")
 */
class Card
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sign;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * Card constructor.
     *
     * @param $sign
     * @param $number
     */
    public function __construct($sign, $number)
    {
        $this->sign = $sign;
        $this->number = $number;

        $this->id = \sprintf('%s_%s', $sign, $number);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $id
     * @return Card
     */
    public function setId(string $id): Card
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

App/Entity/CardPicker.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CardPickerRepository")
 */
class CardPicker
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Card that could be picked.
     *
     * Many CardPicker have Many Card.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Card", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="available_picker_cards",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="card_picker_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="card_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $availableCards;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->availableCards = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return CardPicker
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAvailableCards()
    {
        return $this->availableCards;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $availableCards
     * @return CardPicker
     */
    public function setAvailableCards(array $availableCards)
    {
        $this->availableCards = $availableCards;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addAvailableCard(Card $card)
    {
        if (!$this->availableCards->contains($card)) {
            $this->availableCards->add($card);
        }
    }

    public function removeAvailableCard(Card $card)
    {
        $this->availableCards->removeElement($card);
    }
}
```

App/Repository/CardPickerRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\CardPicker;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method CardPicker|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method CardPicker|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method CardPicker[]    findAll()
 * @method CardPicker[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CardPickerRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    protected $cardRepository;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, CardRepository $cardRepository)
    {
        $this->cardRepository = $cardRepository;
        parent::__construct($registry, CardPicker::class);
    }

    public function initCardPicker(): CardPicker
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $cards = $this->cardRepository->findAll();

        $picker = new CardPicker();
        $picker->setAvailableCards($cards);

        $em->persist($picker);
        $em->flush();

        return $picker;
    }
}
```

App/Repository/CardRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Card;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Card|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Card|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Card[]    findAll()
 * @method Card[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CardRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Card::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the `id` in `Card` is annotated as  `@ORM\GeneratedValue()`. So doctrine will generated a new card each time with new id.

I want to keep always the same card. Just referred to them.